# Force reference to be on last page

Tags: tables, graphics, cross-referencing

I'm writing an article for AAAI 2020 which has its own restriction- reference should be last and without figures after it. In addition, using \newpage or \pagebreak is not allowed at all.

Articles finished this way in.tex:

```
\section{ Acknowledgments}
 text text ...

\bibliography{gan.bib}
\end{document}
```

However, I got images after references.

[image]

Images and tables added this way:

```
\begin{table}[**!htbp**]
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
.....
\end{tabular}

\caption{aaaa}
\label{tbsamplers}
\end{table}
```

Any suggestion on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Don't use the float placement parameters like that. It looks like latex can't find a matching position according to your parameters and places them at the end.

Comment: @DG' what does float placement means?

Comment: The letters you are specifying as an optional argument to `\begin{table}` tell latex where to place the float: `t` for example means top. If latex can't find a place for a float, it puts it at the end → https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Comment: Tried to remove some floats  - doesn't help. There are should be a way to put in at the bottom but before reference